# downloading multiple files with urllib.urlretrieve

Tags: python-2.7, urllib, python-2.x

I'm trying to download multiple files from a website.
The url resembles this:  `foo.com/foo-1.pdf`.
Since I want those files to be stored in a directory of my choice,
I have written the following code:

```
import os
from urllib import urlretrieve
ext = ".pdf"
for i in range(1,37):
    print "fetching file " + str(i)
    url = "http://foo.com/Lec-" + str(i) + ext
    myPath = "/dir/"
    filename = "Lec-"+str(i)+ext
    fullfilename = os.path.join(myPath, filename)
    x = urlretrieve(url, fullfilename)
```

EDIT : Complete error message.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "scraper.py", line 10, in <module>
x = urlretrieve(url, fullfilename)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib.py", line 94, in urlretrieve
return _urlopener.retrieve(url, filename, reporthook, data)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib.py", line 244, in retrieve
tfp = open(filename, 'wb')
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: /dir/Lec-1.pdf'
```

I'd be grateful if someone could point out where I have gone wrong.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You say it should download to `/dir/`. Does this directory exists?

Comment: I checked again and it does exist.

Comment: 1. Can you post the whole error message? 2. You do not need `urlopen(url)`.

Comment: It says that the directory does not exist. Try creating it before the last line with `import os` and `os.makedirs('/dir/', exist_ok=True)`.

Answer (score 0):

As for me your code works (Python3.9). So make sure your script has access to the directory you've specified. Also, it looks like you are trying to open a file which does not exist. So make sure you've downloaded the file before opening it:

```
fullfilename = os.path.abspath("d:/DownloadedFiles/Lec-1.pdf")
print(fullfilename)
if os.path.exists(fullfilename): # open file only if it exists
    with open(fullfilename, 'rb') as file:
        content = file.read() # read file's content
        print(content[:150])  # print only the first 150 characters
```

The output would be as follows:

```
C:/Users/Administrator/PycharmProjects/Tests/dtest.py
d:\DownloadedFiles\Lec-1.pdf
b'%PDF-1.6\r%\xe2\xe3\xcf\xd3\r\n2346 0 obj <</Linearized 1/L 1916277/O 2349/E 70472/N 160/T 1869308/H [ 536 3620]>>\rendobj\r       \r\nxref\r\n2346 12\r\n0000000016 00000 n\r'

Process finished with exit code 0
```

[image]